# How to dynamically create the same input fields upon user request (clicking Add More button)?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, dynamic, html-input

On the Job Positions  page, I would like to have 3 groups of input fields which are static so user can enter Job Name, Job Description, etc. respectively.

I'm not sure what the best approach is but I imagine there would be a button at the bottom which says "Add More". When user clicks on this, it would reveal (say 3) more groups of the input fields. And after entering up to 6 groups, the user can still click "Add More" (perhaps as many times as permissible) to bring up 3 more each time it is clicked.

Hope this is clear enough. I'm slowly getting into the AJAX world.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and use a particular function called append, very easy to do and you'll find the framework simplifying alot of thing for you in the future as well

Comment: Would the instances of the Input boxes be there already but hidden until the "Add More" button is clicked?

Comment: I see, do you know any reference materials that can show me how that is done? Basically once the new instances are created, they need to be picked up in the Code Behind to update the database.

Comment: I have found the Javascript that does that. http://forums.asp.net/p/1611284/4118564.aspx. So how do I get the values of these dynamically created HTML elements from code-behind? Is there a JQuery way which is better?

Comment: I need to see some code... can't just guess myself how you structure is